# How to pass userinput into a class? Python 3.6

Tags: python, class, user-input

I've created a script using python 3.6.6 and the Atom text editor - and when I Run it Powershell I get no errors, so everything looks fine at the moment.

So, here's the script as it looks so far:

```
class Intcalc:
    def __init__(self, name, udbytte, prioritet, score):
        self.name = name
        self.udbytte = udbytte
        self.prioritet = prioritet
        self.score = score

    def beregning(self, udbytte, prioritet, score):
        self.beregning = udbytte + prioritet

    def statement(self):
        print("Your score is: points {}".format(self.score))

class Current(Intcalc):
    def __init__(self, name, udbytte, prioritet, score):
        super().__init__(name, udbytte, prioritet, score = udbytte + prioritet )

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}'s Current Intcalc : Score {}".format(self.name, self.score)
```

And my question is this:

How do I take user inputs and pass it to "udbytte" and "prioritet" in order to calculate "score" based on those user inputs?

I guess i should use: x = float(input("" )) as the line of code to ask for the user input, but if so, where do I place it in the script to make it work?

Comment: You just define these classes — you're not making any instances. This you will need to do anyways, and where you do, you can fill that value.

Comment: All right, thanks, I will try that. And I will return with updates on my progress or lack of the same :-)